# NSDictionary and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

Tried to find the answer here and eventually found a clue on another site.  Posting here in case anyone searches here and has the same problem.

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", YES, 42, nil] 
forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bar", @"baz", @"count", nil]];
```

This produces:

```
Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
```

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`YES` and `42` are not object pointers. You're trying to create an NSArray, which can only contain objects, and you're passing in values that are not pointers to objects. You'll crash for the same reason that

```
[YES description];
```

will crash -- `YES` is not a valid object pointer.

Comment: Right you are.  To clarify further:
NSDictionary is designed to work with pointers.  Thus you must give it pointers to work with. Variables which contain valid pointers will work ok, but the error is specifically caused by treating something like "42" as an address in memory - hence the aptly named error.

Comment: ha ha you beat me to it.  Should probably also do [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] correct?

Comment: Yes, certainly, NSDictionary also wants pointers. In the code you cited, though, the problem is that you're creating an NSArray with values that are not pointers. You'll have a problem whether or not you're using that array to build a dictionary.

Comment: So what would the compiler do with that anyway? cast it to a pointer?  Then try to access that address at runtime?

Comment: @Lone Gunman - I'd guess yes - that would explain the memory bad access error.
@Caleb - good point.

Comment: @Lone Gunman, the compiler will issue a warning that your code "makes pointer from integer without cast." Casting isn't something the compiler does, it's what you do to tell the compiler: "trust me, I know what I'm doing." So in this case, you get a warning, and if you ignore it, your app behaves incorrectly and likely crashes.

Comment: Ugh - thanks. I'd forgotton, as in I was using a long. So, [NSNumber numberWithLong:myLong] sorted me.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, in your array, YES and 42 are not objects. Try using [NSNumber numberWithInt:42] there.  You should have got a compiler warning there.

Answer (score 0):

A int nor a BOOL are objects and therefore cannot be part of a NSDictionary.  Instead of using int's and bools use their object equivalent of a NSNumber.  You can easily store a int using:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)]
```

You can store a BOOL with:

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool:(BOOL)]
```